# SQL Select same columns from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope you are all well!

I am in a situation where I have to make a SQL query to get my hands on minimum and maximum value from two columns with the same type of data limited to only one of each and same name but in two different tables.
Currently I have a query where I can get this from one of the tables, but I can't wrap my head around how to get the MIN datetime value between the two tables and MAX datetime value between the two tables.

In order to get the MAX and MIN from one table only I do like this:

```
SELECT idprojects, projectname, MIN(startDate), MAX(endDate)
FROM projects,
     tasks
WHERE idprojects = projectid
GROUP BY projectid
```

Basically the tables are tables of tasks and subproject tasks where I wan't to display the duration of an entire project by showcasing the first date of the earliest datetime task/sptask and the latest datetime task/sptask.
My tables looks like this:

[image: Here's sptask table]

[image: Here's task table]

[image: Here's project table]

So the result I'd like to get out is only one row pr. projectid with:

```
| projectName | idprojects | MIN(startDate) | MAX(endDate) |
```

Where MIN(startDate) and MAX(startDate) is the allround minimum and maximum datetime values between both sptasks and tasks tables.

I really hope some one can help me here, as I've come nowhere for the time I've been trying.

Have a good one, and be safe!

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except the ones who are arguments to set functions. (Your GROUP BY is invalid and will raise an error with newer MySQL versions, unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left join` as it is not necessary that task or sptask is available for each project. Also, you can use `greatest` and `least` as follows:

```
SELECT p.idprojects, p.projectname, 
       MIN(least(coalesce(t.startDate,s.startdate),
                 coalesce(s.startDate,t.startdate))) as startdate,
       MAX(greatest(coalesce(t.endDate,s.enddate),
                    coalesce(s.endDate,t.enddate))) as enddate
  FROM projects p 
  left join tasks t on p.idprojects = t.projectid
  left join sptasks s on p.idprojects = s.projectid
GROUP BY p.idprojects, p.projectname
```

Comment: Hi Popeye, and thanks for your answer! As the teaching I've had in sql is minimal I can not really understand your query I believe. I get this error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as startdate,        MAX(greatest(coalesce(t.endDate,s.enddate),                ' at line 3

Comment: Check now. Cloaing bracket was missing.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks a lot for your help! Can you, as a last thing, explain to me what coalesce is and what it does in this situation?

Comment: Coalesce returns first not null value and it is needed here because your two tasks table can not have same number of row and for some of the records of any of the table we will not get dates. So to handle that situation, i have added the coalesce to replace value with itself

Comment: Hi Popeye, I know its been a while, but I sit here looking back at it and am at this time wondering why it is both MIN(least) and MAX(greatest). I'd have thought it was more or less the same? :) Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You need UNION not JOIN here-- like this:

```
SELECT projectid, projectName , MIN(startDate), MAX(endDate)
FROM (
  SELECT projectid, projectName , startDate, endDate
  FROM projects
  UNION ALL
  SELECT projectid, projectName , startDate, endDate
  FROM tasks
) x
GROUP BY projectid, projectName
```

Comment: Hi Hogan, I believe that wouldn't work, as you select dates from projects

Comment: Giving me this error as well: Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @rasm937k -- just needed to put an alias on the sub-query -- I edited it above.